# Vim scrolling with touchpad too sensitive

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2, macos-sierra

I'm using vim (7.4.898) on Mac OS Sierra and iTerm2 (latest version). I have `set mouse=a` enabled in my `.vimrc`. Since the upgrade to Mac OS Sierra, the scrolling with the touchpad in vim is way too sensitive. Scrolling otherwise works fine. Is there a way to adjust the sensitivity somewhere (either in MacOS, iTerm2 or vim)?

Comment: You probably may be able to ply with `:set ttyscroll` or `:set ttyfast` to make full redraws instead of scrolls in Vim but that would give a huge CPU kick.  The right configuration place is at X11 level (no clue how to do that on a Mac though).

Comment: Thanks. But no luck yet.

Comment: This is a known issue with Sierra unfortunately. I have an open issue with Apple; I suggest you also report at http://bugreport.apple.com. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7679256?start=0&tstart=0
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7659385?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I am now using a new MackBook Pro. The scrolling issue completely disappeared for me.